# Automating a Local HTML file to open each morning with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, automation

I have a Local HTML/CSS Document on my computer that I want to open up every time I either log in to my computer or at a certain time each day.

I am wanting to run this with JavaScript and not a .bat file if possible.

I have code that can let you select what file you want to open but not one that is automated to a certain time.

Code:

```
function readSingleFile(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    displayContents(contents);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.textContent = contents;
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

I am new to javascript so if this not possible then I will try to find another way.

Comment: If you can have this webpage open 24/7 perhaps a setTimeout and Date class may help you

Comment: @RobertI if this is not possible what other ways could I perform the above?

Comment: Use setInterval() of 24 hrs, i.e 24*60*60*1000 as interval

Comment: If you're on Windows, you will have to create a service (I believe they can be written in C#) and if you're on Linux you can write a script to run on startup

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript running in a webpage cannot do anything in response to you logging in, and it can't do anything at a particular time of day unless the page the JS runs in is already loaded into a browser window.

You will need to rewrite your script to use a mechanism that doesn't depend on the browser to have opened a page.

Since you mentioned .bat files, I assume you are using Windows.

You could use Windows Scripting Host (or possibly Node.js) to run the JS. You would need to rewrite it to work with their APIs and explicitly launch a browser to display the page.

(While you have rejected .bat files as an option, it would probably be infinitely simpler to use one for this).

You can then schedule your script (whether written in JS or Batch) to run on login or at a particular time using [Windows Task Schedular](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7).

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler can run any program, so if his end goal is just to open a local HTML file he can set it up to run his preferred browser and pass the file name as the argument, no script file required.